# Jetpack Compose animateContentSize for Row or Column with proper content animation

Tags: android, animation, android-jetpack-compose

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        .padding(bottom = 16.dp)
        .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
        .background(AppTheme.colors.tetriary, shape = AppTheme.shapes.medium)
        .animateContentSize(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 2000))
        .height(AppDimens.Size.size_48)
        .width(
            if (someBoolean) {
                256.dp
            } else {
                128.dp
            }
        ),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
        .background(color = AppTheme.colors.secondaryGreen))
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
        .background(color = AppTheme.colors.redDark))
}
```

I created this sample for testing. While animateContentSize correctly changes bounds of Row container (with AppTheme.colors.tetriary background), spacers jump to the final position at the start of animation.

I'm not experienced in Compose framework and somehow I can't find any best practice for this case.
So my question is how I need to animate positions of content properly (I want them to always stay at the center of the row) [Here is some visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooMKO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found a solution using

```
val animatedWidth by animateDpAsState(
    targetValue = if (someBoolean) 256.dp else 128.dp,
    label = "animatedWidth"
)
...
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        ...
        .width(animatedWidth),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, i meant something like this :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for now. Your problem is related to static definition of your width values. When you think you fired off your animation compose actually remeasure this row and determine its new constraints so this constraints are at the start 128dp and at the end 256dp and spacers relocate themselves according to this constraints not to a visual deferation. I will definitely find a much more elegant solution but just to give an idea you can approach the problem in this way:

```
                var animated by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                val animatable = remember { Animatable(128f) }
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

                Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                            .padding(bottom = 16.dp)
                            .background(Color.Green, shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                            .height(48.dp)
                            .width(animatable.value.dp),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {


                        Spacer(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(24.dp)
                                .background(color = Color.Red)
                        )
                        Spacer(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(24.dp)
                                .background(color = Color.Cyan)
                        )
                    }


                    Button(onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            if (animated) {
                                animatable.animateTo(128f)
                                animated = false
                            } else {
                                animatable.animateTo(256f)
                                animated = true
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text(text = "Expand or not")
                    }
                }
```